# Auto change and disable lesser value in another radio field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a rather complex scenario. I'm just a newbie trying to learn javascript.

When a user clicks value in option-1, the lesser value in option-2 must be disabled and moved to a higher value. For instance, if a user selects `15` in option-1, than `10` and `15` must be disabled in option-2. Then, it must auto move the selected value to `20`.

Note that if a user selects `5` in option-1, he/she can select any higher value in option-2.

```js
$('#option1 :radio').on('change', function() {
  document.getElementById("value1").value = $(this).val();
  document.getElementById("value2").value = $(this).val();
});
$('#option2 :radio').on('change', function() {
  document.getElementById("value11").value = $(this).val();
  document.getElementById("value12").value = $(this).val();
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h6>Option 1</h6>
  <div id="option1" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="5" id="option" autocomplete="off"> 5</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="10" id="option" autocomplete="off"> 10</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="15" id="option" autocomplete="off"> 15</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="20"id="option" autocomplete="off"> 20</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="value1" value="5" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="value2" value="5" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="container">
  <h6>Option 2</h6>
  <div id="option2" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-flex" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100 active">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="10" id="option" autocomplete="off"> 10</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="15" id="option" autocomplete="off"> 15</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="20" id="option" autocomplete="off"> 20</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary w-100">
      <input type="radio" name="options" value="25"id="option" autocomplete="off"> 25</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="value11" value="10" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="value12" value="10" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/42zebu3f/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition in the `change` event for the `option1` elements where it takes the current value and compares it with values from the `option2` and then adds the disable attribute to the lesser value than that selected.

You should change your code from this:

```
$('#option1 :radio').on('change', function() {
  document.getElementById("value1").value = $(this).val();
  document.getElementById("value2").value = $(this).val();
});
```

To this:

```
$('#option1 :radio').on('change', function() {
  document.getElementById("value1").value = $(this).val();
  document.getElementById("value2").value = $(this).val();
  var baseValue = parseInt($(this).val());

  var option2List = $('#option2 :radio').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val()) <= baseValue; //getting only the values lesser to the current and equal to it
  });
  $('#option2 :radio').removeAttr('disabled');//resetting the option2
  $('#option2 label').removeClass('disabled');//resetting the labels 
  option2List.prop('disabled', 'disabled'); //disabling the lesser values
  //below code adds the disabled class to the labels  
  $.each(option2List,function(){
    $(this).closest('label').addClass('disabled');
  });
  $('#option2 :radio:enabled').first().click();//selects the first enabled element
});
```

Comment: While it updated the underlying radios, it doesn't change the state of the Bootstrap button group. Nor does it select the first available radio in `#option2`

Comment: didn't read the selected change value state doing the changes

Comment: This is amazing!! Thank You so much. Bootstrap CSS doesn't seem to understand the radio buttons' `disabled` featured. Probably because I'm using `<label>`.

Comment: btw, could we add a class to <label> tag in option-2 as well when it is disabled? Say `btn-disabled` class name so I can change the design of the disabled button?

Comment: @vikscool That's so amazing. I can't thank you enough for this :)